# prepopulating Angular material select having grouping

Tags: angular6, angular-material-6

I had used angular material select

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="category"
            required>
  <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of categoryGroups"
                [label]="group.name">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let category of group.options"
                [value]="category.value" (onSelectionChange)="onCategorySelection($event, group.name)">
       {{category.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-optgroup>

</mat-select>
```

but having problem in case of UPDATE form it should be prepopute based on data passed.

As there is having same category value might be present in another group.

So not able to prepopulate mat-select

As there binding for mat-select without grouping : `[value] = "category.value"`

i.e. Based on group option should be prepopulated
Please check  :

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsg3cl?embed=1&file=src/app/select-optgroup-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Each option must have a unique value. You can set the value to anything you want - it does not have to be the "category" value. For example, you could prepend the group name to the category value:

```
[value]="group.name + '-' + pokemon.value"
```